# Ruby on rails: Hostname not found gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, push

I'm working on a app where i use ruby on rails as server script. and my code was working fine but when i change the server. i get this error whenever i try to send a push notification.

```
Hostname not found: Gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
```

and code pushcode:

```
pusher = Grocer.pusher(
  certificate: "#{Rails.root}/public/PinkDev.pem",      # required
  #certificate: "#{Rails.root}/public/PinkDist.pem",      # required
  passphrase:  'xxxxxxx',                       # optional
  #gateway:     "gateway.push.apple.com", # optional; See note below.
  gateway:     "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", # sandbox.
  port:        2195,                     # optional
  retries:     3                         # optional
)
notification = Grocer::Notification.new(
  device_token: "#{device_token}",
  alert: "#{alert}",
  sound: "default",
  content_available: true,
  badge:count,
  custom: {
  "others": {:device_token =>xxxxx,:access_token=>xxxxx, :alert=>xxxx,:push_type=>xxxx,:xxxxx=> xxx,:xxxx=>xxxx, :user_id=>xxxx, :badge=>xxxxx}}
)
pusher.push(notification)
```

how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like your old computer had `"gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com"` gateway set explicitly somewhere in `/etc/hosts` or wherever it’s set on MacO$.

Comment: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com seems to be a public DNS record, so this is more likely an issue with DNS configuration on whatever machine this code is running on

Comment: This is most likely not a Ruby (or Rails) issue. Your machine can't resolve the hostname `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` for some reason. You can use the `host` utility for DNS lookup. From the command line, enter `host gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`. If that doesn't work, try with another DNS server, e.g. `host gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 8.8.8.8`